# Spring boot application throwing 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to build a basic spring boot application of  spring security and when I start the application and hit the URL it throws 404 not found error.

Here is the code

### Springsecurity1Application.java

```
package com.kpr.springsecurity1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurity1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurity1Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

### MainController.java

```
package com.kpr.springsecurity1.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping("/open")
    public String open(){
        return "This is open";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String user(){
        return "This is open";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return "This is open";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/none")
    public String none(){
        return "This is open";
    }
}
```

### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.kpr</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I Tried with @RestController instead of @controller it worked but with @Controller it did not work

Here is directory structure

[directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H81ol.png)

This is the error
[Eror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpBSo.png)

Comment: You probably need a template engine such as Thymeleaf.  The return string is the name of the template.

Comment: you need to use `@RestController` if you want endpoints

Answer (score -1):

The issue in your code is that you are returning plain strings from your controller methods: Spring takes its logical view name to return and tries to find the HTML page or JSP page; that is the reason why you got a 404 error .

In Spring Boot, if you are using @Controller, then you can also use @ResponseBody – it works fine.

Otherwise, replace @Controller with @RestController.

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @RequestMapping("/open")
    public String open(){
        return "open"; // Return the view name "open"
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String user(){
        return "user"; // Return the view name "user"
    }

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(){
        return "admin"; // Return the view name "admin"
    }

    @RequestMapping("/none")
    public String none(){
        return "none"; // Return the view name "none"
    }
}
```